# How to share big data

Tags: linux, ftp, dropbox, http, google-drive

I want to share 1TB of compressed data, but I want that the files can be downloaded with wget?

I have tried GitHub and Google drive, but I can't get the files with wget. How can I share big data?

Comment: Because it is free to download data from the internet into Amazon AWS, and you need to pay if you transfer data from outside into AWS with scp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem why you can't download those files with `wget` is that wget needs direct link.

To get direct link od GitHub you need to have your adress starting with `raw.github.com` or to click Raw button.

[image: Raw]

How to get Direct link on Google Drive there's explanation in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665881/direct-download-from-google-drive-using-google-drive-api)

Another options you can use is to choose file sharing sites which can support direct linking or to host yourself file server with protocol `wget` can handle.